# Functions h and r: prove $||h||_p = sup_{||r||_q \le 1} \int_E{rh}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Functions h and r: prove $||h||_p = sup_{||r||_q \le 1} \int_E{rh}$, where $1/p + 1/q =1$. 
Using Holder's Inequality, I can prove that $||h||_p \le sup_{||r||_q \le 1} \int_E{rh}$, but I'm having trouble with the opposite direction

Comment: Hölder's inequality gives you the inequality $\displaystyle \sup_{\|r\|_q \le 1} \int_E fh \le \|h\|_p$.  The other inequality is in general false unless you make some assumptions about the underlying measure space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset E_3 \subset \cdots$ be measurable sets with finite measure satisfying $X = \cup_n E_n$.

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $X$.  Define functions $\{h_n\}$ by $h_n(x) = |f(x)|$ if $|f(x)| \le n$ and $x \in E_n$. Otherwise let $h_n(x) = 0$. Observe that $0 \le h_1(x) \le h_2(x) \le h_3(x) \le \cdots$ and that $h_n(x) \to |f(x)|$ for all $x$. Note that $$\|h_n\|_p \le n \mu(E_n)^{1/p} < \infty$$ for all $n$, and $\|h_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ by the monotone convergence theorem.

If $\|h\|_p = 0$ then $h$ is identically zero and $\displaystyle \|h\|_p = \sup_{\|r\|_q \le 1} \int_X rh \, d\mu = 0$.

Assume without loss of generality that $0 < \|h\|_p \le \infty$ and also without loss of generality that $\|h_n\|_p > 0$ for all $n$.

Since $$\|h_n\|_p^p = \int_X h_n^p \, d\mu$$ it follows that
$$ \|h_n\|_p = \int_X h_n \left( \frac{h_n}{\|h_n\|_p} \right)^{p-1} \, d\mu \le \int_X |f| \left( \frac{h_n}{\|h_n\|_p} \right)^{p-1} \, d\mu.$$

It is readily checked that $$\left\| \left( \frac{h_n}{\|h_n\|_p} \right)^{p-1} \right\|_q = 1$$ so that
$$ \|h_n\|_p \le \sup_{\|r\|_q \le 1} \int_X |fr| \, d\mu = \sup_{\|r\|_q \le 1} \int_X fr \, d\mu.$$ Finally let $n \to \infty$ to conclude 
$$\|f\|_p \le \sup_{\|r\|_q \le 1} \int_X fr \, d\mu.$$

A final word of caution: the last supremum is taken over all $f \in L^q$ with norm not exceeding $1$ and for which $\int_X fr$ is actually defined (and a priori possibly infinite).

Comment: This is just great!

Answer (score 0):

First we assume $\Vert h \Vert_p=1.$

Take

$$ r(x) = sgn(x)\cdot h^{p-1}(x) $$

Then

$$ \Vert r \Vert_q = \left( \int_E \vert h\vert^{q\cdot(p-1)}  \right)^{1/q} = \Vert h \Vert_{p}^{p/q}=1.$$

Hence,

$$ \Vert h \Vert_p = 1 = \Vert h \Vert_p^p = \int_E \vert h(x)\vert^p = \int_E r h \leq \sup_{\Vert s\Vert_q \leq 1} \int_E sh.$$

The general case follows now (let $h\neq 0$)

$$ \Vert h \Vert_p =  \Vert h \Vert_p \cdot \Vert\frac{h}{\Vert h \Vert_p}\Vert_p \leq \Vert h \Vert_p \cdot \sup_{\Vert s\Vert_q \leq 1} \int_E s\frac{h}{\Vert h \Vert_p} = \sup_{\Vert s\Vert_q \leq 1} \int_E sh.$$

For the converse inequality we just apply Hölder's inequality:

$$ \sup_{\Vert s\Vert_q \leq 1} \int_E sh \leq \sup_{\Vert s\Vert_q \leq 1} \Vert s h \Vert_1 \leq \sup_{\Vert s\Vert_q \leq 1} \Vert s \Vert_q \cdot \Vert h \Vert_p = \Vert h \Vert_p.$$

Comment: Can you prove the result without assuming a priori that $\|h\|_p$ is finite?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I tried, but it didn't work out. If you can find a proof, I'd really be interested.

Comment: If the underlying space is $\sigma$-finite you can start by truncating $f$ and restricting to sets of large finite measure. If the underlying space is not $\sigma$-finite the inequality may not be true.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I understand you correctly. I mean it might be possible (independent of $\sigma$-finiteness) that the preimage of a single value has infinite measure, e.g. $1_{\mathbb{R}}$. Then truncating $f$ would not be enough.

Comment: You can write $\mathbb R$ as an increasing union of sets $E_n$ each of which has finite measure. You can first consider $f \chi_{E_n}$ and then take monotone limits.

Comment: Sure, but the measure of your simple functions goes to infinity. We take the supremum only over the ones which have norm 1.

Comment: I put the details in a separate answer.